# Centering tikzpicture in tabularray

Tags: tikz-pgf, tabularray

in my table, I would like the 2nd tikzpicture column to be centered (like the word "convergent") and each word in the 4th column cell to be centered as well ("biconvex" is bottom centered relative to the lens representation)

[image]

My code :

```
    \documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
hline{2,5}={blue},
colspec={Q[c] Q[c] Q[c] Q[c]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m]},
cell{2}{1}={r=3}{c},
cell{5}{1}={r=3}{c},
colsep=3pt,
row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
}
type de lentille & représentation schématique & forme & représentation\\
convergente & \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw[<->] (0,0) -- (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}& biconvexe & \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw (0,-1) to[bend left=30] (0,1) to [bend left=30] (0,-1);

\end{tikzpicture}\\
 &   & plan convexe & \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw (0,-1) to[bend left=30] (0,1) to (0,-1);

\end{tikzpicture}\\
 &  & ménisque convergent & \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw (0,-1) to[bend left=40] (0,1) to [bend right=20] (0,-1);

\end{tikzpicture}\\
divergente &  & biconcave & \\
& & plan concave & \\
& & ménisque divergent & \\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

Comment: are you really loosing all your accented chars like é  as shown in the picture??

Comment: @UlrikeFischer No, it's just for the WME

Comment: but your MWE wouldn't do that. So why do you show a  picture from another document?

Comment: I exported the table to a single document and forgot to save the document as utf8 (and since that wasn't the main problem, I left the image)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
hline{2,5}={blue},
colspec={Q[c] Q[c] Q[c] Q[c]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m]},
cell{2}{1}={r=3}{c},
cell{2}{2}={r=3}{c},
cell{5}{1}={r=3}{c},
colsep=3pt,
row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
}
type de lentille & représentation schématique & forme & représentation\\
convergente & \tikz \draw[<->] (0,0) -- (0,2); & biconvexe & \\
&  & plan convexe & \\
&  & ménisque convergent & \\
divergente &  & biconcave & \\
& & plan concave & \\
& & ménisque divergent & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table with text and an double arrow]

Answer (score 2):

I would write your table on the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={baseline, yscale=0.5}}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={@{} Q[c,wd=5em] Q[c,wd=8em] c Q[c,m] @{}}, 
             rowsep=3pt,
             row{1}={cmd=\textbf, m}, 
            }
    \toprule[blue]
type de lentille
    & représentation schématique
        & forme 
            & représentation        \\
    \midrule[blue]
\SetCell[r=3]{m}    convergente 
    &   \SetCell[r=3]{m}
        \tikz\draw[<->] (0,-3) -- (0,3);    
        & biconvexe 
            &   \tikz\draw (0,-1) to[bend left] (0,1) to [bend left] (0,-1);
                                    \\
    &   \tikz[baseline]
            \draw[<->] (0,-2) -- (0,2);
        & plan convexe 
            &   \tikz\draw (0,-1) to[bend left] (0,1) to (0,-1);
                                    \\
    &   & ménisque convergent 
            &   \tikz\draw (0,-1) to[bend left] (0,1) to [bend right=15] (0,-1);
                                    \\
     \midrule[blue]
    &   &   biconcave             
        &   \tikz\draw (-.5,-1) to[bend right] (-0.5,1) -- (0.5,1)  
                                to[bend right] (0.5,-1) -- cycle;
                                    \\
divergente
    &   & plan concave         
        &   \tikz\draw (-.5,-1) to[bend right] (-0.5,1) 
                                -- (0,1) |- cycle;
                                    \\
    &   & ménisque divergent 
            &   \tikz\draw (0,-1) to[bend right=15] (0,1) to [bend left] (0,-1);
                                    \\
    \bottomrule[blue]
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on a solution given to me by user egreg:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\AtBeginDocument{\sbox0{$x$}}% to be sure the math fonts are computed
\tikzset{baseshift/.style={yshift=-\the\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2}}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tblr}{
            vspan=even, hspan=minimal,
            hline{2,5}={blue},
            colspec={Q[c] Q[c] Q[c] Q[c]}, rowspec={Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m] Q[m]},
            cell{2}{1}={r=3}{c},
            cell{5}{1}={r=3}{c},
            colsep=3pt,
            row{1}={cmd=\textbf},
        }
        type de lentille & représentation schématique & forme & représentation\\
        convergente & & biconvexe & \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline={([baseshift]current bounding box.center)}]
            \draw (0,-1) to[bend left=30] (0,1) to [bend left=30] (0,-1);
            
        \end{tikzpicture}\\
        & \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline={([baseshift]current bounding box.center)}]
            \draw[<->] (0,0) -- (0,2);
        \end{tikzpicture}  & plan convexe & \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline={([baseshift]current bounding box.center)}]
            \draw (0,-1) to[bend left=30] (0,1) to (0,-1);
            
        \end{tikzpicture}\\
        &  & ménisque convergent & \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,baseline={([baseshift]current bounding box.center)}]
            \draw (0,-1) to[bend left=40] (0,1) to [bend right=20] (0,-1);
            
        \end{tikzpicture}\\
        divergente &  & biconcave & \\
        & & plan concave & \\
        & & ménisque divergent & \\
    \end{tblr}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]